# Multiplication in MIPS by shifting and adding, without mult

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have the following code, but I keep receiving an Arithmetic Overflow error. The problem that I am trying to solve is multiplying two 31-bit numbers together and storing the results in $t2 $t3 and printing out the correct result. It seems that I have coded for two numbers to be multiplied and the end result is a 31-bit number.

I would love to narrow down where I feel like I am going wrong, but I honestly cannot see where and what I need to change.

```
# program to multiply two 31 bit binary numbers (A & B),

# using the “shift and add” .

.data

# declare the variable lables of ASCII storage type.

prompt1: .asciiz "Enter number 1: "

prompt2: .asciiz "Enter number 2: "

result: .asciiz "The multiplication of two 31 bit binary numbers is: "

.text
```

main:

```
            #prompt1.

            li $v0, 4   

            la $a0, prompt1

            syscall

           #read number 1 and store in the register $t0

            li $v0, 5        

            syscall  

            move $t0, $v0

         

            #prompt2.

            li $v0, 4   

            la $a0, prompt2

            syscall

           

            #read number 2 and store in the register $t1

            li $v0, 5        

            syscall  

            move $t1, $v0

                          

            li $t2, 0 # The final result of the multiplication

                            #is saved into the register $t2

            li $t3, 1 # Mask for extracting bit!

            li $s1, 0 # set the Counter to 0 for loop.
```

multiply:

```
            #if the Counter $s1 is equal to 31, then go the lable exit

            beq $s1, 31, exit

            and $s2, $t1, $t3

            sll $t3, $t3, 1

                    beq $s2, 0, increment

            add $t2, $t2, $t0
```

increment:

```
            sll $t0, $t0, 1

            addi $s1, $s1, 1

            j multiply
```

exit:

```
            #display the result string.

            li $v0, 4   

            la $a0, result

            syscall

                            #display the result value.

            li $v0, 1

            add $a0, $t2, $zero

            syscall

         

            li $v0, 10 # system call code for exit = 10

            syscall   # call operating sys
```

Sample input A: 1143330295 (Decimal)
Sample input B: 999999223  (Decimal)

Comment: Your algorithm seems correct, but when you multiply two 32 bits numbers, the result is 64 bits. You are probably using a 32 bits mips and with your algorithm you have an arithmetic overflow.  You can use $t3 to store lsb part of the result, and  in the loop instead of shifting $t0 in increment,  a/ keep the lsb of $t2 in $t4 b/ `srl $t2 $t2 1`  and `srl $t3,$t3,1` c/ reinject the lsb of $t4 in the msb of $t3 by shifting it by 31 and oring it with $t3.

Comment: I thought the same thing as far as storing part of it in $t3 to avoid the error. I tried implementing what you said but I think I am modifying the wrong parts. You have been extremely helpful so far. I am sure you are going to hate me, but any chance you could modify it based on your comment. I seem to be modifying it wrong. I apologize I am brand new to assembly and it is still a bit hazy, perhaps if I visualized your thought process it would make it much clearer for me. I would greatly appreciate it. I really want to learn how this process works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible implementation.

Differences from your code :

- a 32x32 multiplication generates a 64 bit result. On a 32 bits mips, result must be split in two registers
- instead of left shifting operand, that will drive to overflows, result is right shifted. Expelled bits are saved and reinjected in lower part of result
- use addu for the addition. Numbers are unsigned and without unsigned ops overflows may occur
- changed loop in a "do while" form. Loop counter is decremented

Displayed result is presently in two parts. Incorrect display may occur if LSB is set (and is considered as a negative signed by display int syscall)), but most mips simulators do not have a way to display a large unsigned.

```
# program to multiply two 31 bit binary numbers (A & B),
# using the “shift and add” .

.data
# declare the variable lables of ASCII storage type.
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter number 1: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter number 2: "
result: .asciiz "The multiplication of two 31 bit binary numbers is: "
result2: .asciiz "\nand the upper part of result is: "

.text
main:
        #prompt1.
        li $v0, 4   
        la $a0, prompt1
        syscall

        #read number 1 and store in the register $t0
        li $v0, 5        
        syscall  
        move $t0, $v0

        #prompt2.
        li $v0, 4   
        la $a0, prompt2
        syscall

        #read number 2 and store in the register $t1
        li $v0, 5        
        syscall  
        move $t1, $v0

        li $t2, 0 # The final result of the multiplication is 64 bits
                  # MSB part is in register $t2
        li $t4, 0 #  and LSB part of result is in $t4
        li $t3, 1 # Mask for extracting bit!
        li $s1, 32 # set the Counter to 32 for loop.   

multiply:
        and $s2, $t1, $t3
        beq $s2, 0, increment
        addu $t2, $t2, $t0

increment:
        sll $t3, $t3, 1 # update mask
        ##sll $t0, $t0, 1 # useless, we srl result instead
        andi $s4, $t2,1  # save lsb of result
        srl $t2,$t2,1    # t2>>=1
        srl $t4,$t4,1    # t4>>=1
        sll $s4,$s4,31
        or  $t4,$t4,$s4  # reinject saved lsb of result in msb of $t4
        addi $s1, $s1, -1 # decrement loop counter
        #if the Counter $s1 reaches 0 then go the label exit
        beq $s1, $zero, exit
        j multiply

exit:
        #display the result string.
        ## must be changed to take into account the 64 bits of the result
        ## but AFAIK, there is no syscall for that
        ## can be done in two steps t4 and t2
        ## and result is t4+2**32*t2
        #display the result value.
        li $v0, 4   
        la $a0, result
        syscall
        li $v0, 1  # if using mars replace 1 by 36 to print as an unsigned
        add $a0, $t4, $zero
        syscall
        li $v0, 4   
        la $a0, result2
        syscall
        li $v0, 1 # if using mars replace 1 by 36 to print as an unsigned
        add $a0, $t2, $zero
        syscall

        li $v0, 10 # system call code for exit = 10
        syscall   # call operating sys
```

Comment: It's pretty common to only want the low 32 bits of a 32x32 product; presumably that's what the OP was trying to implement.  And BTW, MIPS can branch on the sign bit of a register with one instruction (`bltz`).  But it doesn't have a rotate instruction, so this doesn't help reduce the AND/SLL overhead unless we start from the MSB (and consider the other multiplicand to start out left-shifted by 32).  Or maybe you can use a variable-count shift using the down-counter as the shift-count.  (But then you can't drop it and break out of the loop when you've shifted all the bits out of one operand.)

Comment: I greatly appreciate the help Peter. The comments on each line of code did wonders for my thought process. I can't thank you enough. I feel much better dealing with a problem in this manner.

Comment: @rdopler: I only commented on Alain's answer.  You should thank him by clicking the checkmark under the up/down vote arrows to mark it as "accepted", if you think it sufficiently answers the question.